# how to make CAPTCHA.MVC5 captcha case sensitive in razor Asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, captcha

I am using captch.mvc5 nuget package in my ASP.NET MVC project, but how can I

```html
                                <div class="row form-group">
                                    @Html.Label("Enter Captcha ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-sm-4" })
                                    <div class="col-offset-4 col-md-8">
                                        @Html.Captcha("Refresh", "Enter Captcha Text", 5, "Is required field", true)
                                        @Html.ValidationMessage("Captchaerror", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

make it make my captcha case-sensitive and alphanumeric

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer:

--IF YOU ARE USING CAPTCHA.MVC5 NUGET PACKAGE IN MVC --- YOU CAN MAKE IT ALPHANUMERIC AND CASE SENSITIVE BY THE FOLLOWING---

a) open Global.asax file.

b) In Application_Start() method add the above code.

c) set `ignoreCase = false;` as above for case sensitive data.

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
       //---Your default code if available ------

        //--Captcha-- 
        var captchaManager = (DefaultCaptchaManager)CaptchaUtils.CaptchaManager;
       //-- this will generate  alphanumeric string------------------
        captchaManager.CharactersFactory = () => "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; 
        captchaManager.PlainCaptchaPairFactory = length =>
        {
            string randomText = RandomText.Generate(captchaManager.CharactersFactory(), length);
            bool ignoreCase = false;//This parameter is responsible for ignoring case.
            return new KeyValuePair<string, ICaptchaValue>(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
                new StringCaptchaValue(randomText, randomText, ignoreCase));
        };
    }
```